# Clone Java NamingEnumeration?

Tags: java, variables, clone

Just wondering if there is a way to clone a NamingEnumeration in Java? My program searches an LDAP server for people and it can take a few seconds to complete. To get the number of results I am using the following:

```
NamingEnumeration results = null;
NamingEnumeration results2 = null;

results = ctx.search("", "("+searchAt+"=" +searchVal +")", controls);
results2 = result;
int i = 0;
while(results2.hasMore())
{
    results2.next();
    i++;
}
```

But since results2 is just a reference to result when i go through displaying the results results.hasMore() will always return false.

is there a way to clone 'results' without having to re-preform the search and assign it to 'results2'?

Thanks, -Pete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Collections.list(results) to put the results in a list and then use List.size to get the count, and iterate over the list.

Answer (score 4):

There is no guarantee that if you redo the search you'll get the same answer back.

The simple solution is to copy the results into a `List` (`ArrayList` to be specific).

Answer (score 3):

In general if you need to make a copy of an `Enumeration` (or `Iterator`) you move the contents to a `List`.  Most enumerations are not directly cloneable.  You can create the list by hand or use the method `Collections.list` (which I missed for a moment there).